# Why is the first parameter of the std::error_code constructor fixed to an int

Tags: c++, c++11, std, error-code

Since I've learned about std::error_code, I'm using it a lot and I love the minimalist and flexible design of this library. But I'm disturbed by one issue. What is the reason to define the constructor of std::error_code like this:

```
error_code( int ec, const error_category& ecat ) noexcept;
```

This prevents clients from using 64-bit error_codes in an environment where an int is compiled with 32-Bit (which is true for all Visual Studio compilers). Wouldn't it be far more flexible to use a type that can be adapted to the platform like `std::size_t`? Or, to provide the user with full control over the underlying integer type, to introduce a `std::basic_error_code` template class to get a behaviour similar to `std::basic_string` with its typedefs `std::string` and `std::wstring`:

```
namespace std
{
    template<class IntT>
    class basic_error_code
    {  
    public:
        basic_error_code(IntT ec, const error_category& cat)
            : _Myec(ec)
            , _Mycat(&cat)
        {}

        ...

    private:
        IntT  _Myec;
        const error_category *_Mycat;
    };

    using error_code = basic_error_code<int>;
} // namespace std
```

Of course it would be necessary to add an additional conversion constructor for 64-bit error_codes to be able to work with `std::error_code` which is using 32-bit, but I see currently no problem to define one.

**Update**

I appreciate all your answers and of course, you are right in general; there is no need of so many error codes.

But let me give you two examples, where it would make sense nevertheless:

1. If you have an existing code from another system, which doesn't use std::error_code and this code uses 64-Bit values (maybe you don't want to use all of these codes but only a sup-range). You can easily convert this code into a std::error_code by defining your own category. If you have additionaly a #define list of all these codes, it is really just a little copy and paste, because you can use the #define macro names right in your enum.
2. If you want to use an | operation to combine different error_codes into one. It is possible and operates very well in combination with the std::error_code framework (I've already implemented such a system). In this case, you run really fast out of possibilities, if you can only use 32-Bit. 
   Well, before you complain about the uniqueness of an error_code, which is a combination of different error_codes; this is not really a problem, because you have error conditions, which can mask away the unwanted error_code part to fetch back the original error_code (the one, which you had, before you used the | operation)

I'm looking forward to hear further comments about this topic.

Comment: you really need more than 2^32 error codes?

Comment: If your code can fail in more than 4 billion ways and you need more than 2^32 error codes you can just create a second category which will cover the second 4 billion different ways your code can fail...

Comment: i am afraid there is no better answer to your question than: because it is sufficient

Comment: Having `basic_error_code` makes no sense - the whole point of `std::error_code` is to unify error reporting, not to divide it further.

Comment: Do you have an actual system, for which 32-bit is not enough (I'm curious, all the systems I know uses at most 32-bit codes)?

Comment: std::error_code doesn't have to hold only codes, which represent error conditions. Also well defined states of the program can be propagated with a std::error_code. For example, think of a error category, which maps an error_code to a REST response. You definitively will have an error_code "200", which means: "everything is ok"

Answer (score 0):

`std::error_code` is designed to wrap/replace various existing error systems like `errno` and `HRESULT` which use 32-bit error codes (`int` in the case of `errno` and `LONG` for `HRESULT`).

I can't envisage a situation where you would need more than 4 billion (2^32) error codes in a single category. For example `errno` gets by with providing error codes for most of posix with around 130 error codes.

Using a larger type would require more memory usage for no benefit.

Comment: There is a notable exception to "larger type would require more memory usage for no benefit": 64-bit systems. `error_category` is stored as a pointer into `error_code`, so because of padding, 64-bit `ec` wouldn't make the size larger.

Comment: I agree with many of the responses that say you should never need more than 4billion error codes! But the problem, going back to the original question, is "what do you do when you're trying to wrap a library/system that uses error values that are larger than an int?"
For example, OpenSSL uses unsigned long for its errors. How would you handle that for most modern systems where an int is 32-bits and a long is 64-bits?

Comment: @FrankP I've not looked at OpenSSL's error codes but I imagine in reality they're only actually using 32-bits, the use of `long` is likely a legacy from 32-bit systems and in order to retain compatibility with 32-bit systems I expect their error codes actually fit in 32-bits

Comment: @FrankP yep, they're 32-bit https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/df04e81794ac3083804c34c173eb2b2fa55d373d/include/openssl/err.h.in#L181

Comment: Thanks, @AlanBirtles. I had figured that out, but thought to keep the question up for ideas if that weren't the case. I guess the answer I was looking for was to hope that a library using a `long` or similar, would chunk up the codes into groups, each with an `int` sized number of sub-codes so that could each chunk could be represented by a different `error_category`.  For example, the OpenSSL errors are broken into bit fields for library/function/reason. At worst, each (sub)library could have been represented by a different category.